# Создание статичного объекта

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как можно объявить объект `div`, чтобы использовать его как шаблон (без функции)?

```
div = $('<div class="not"></div>');
   a = div.addClass('x');
   b = div.addClass('y');
   c = div.addClass('z');
alert(div.attr('Class')); // <-- Чтобы у div остался только класс "not"
```

Comment: Никак. Вы либо меняете этот div за счет вызовов .addClass(), либо нет.

Comment: а может div.clone() подойдет?

Comment: @Etki, Опять не как ответ? :)

Comment: @zhenyab, clone() то работает, но мне хотелось не писать лишнего. Пришлось делать через функцию `function div() {return $('<div></div>');} div().addClass('x');`

Аж прям не знаю, профы в меня какашками закидают и присвоят статус "говнокодер"

![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://vk.com/images/emoji_2x/D83DDCA9.png

Comment: @Doofy, в jQuery html принято создавать так:

    $('<div>', {'class': 'superclass', 'data-item-id': someId});

ваша функция легко заменяется на

    $('<div>').addClass('x');